# Html5 - window.onbeforeunload to catch _only_ refresh, back/forward

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "u sure?";
}
```

Only on refresh, forward/back events. Currently this code catches everything. I don't want it to catch link clicks or form post events. Also, I need to have all the code inside of that function, so I was thinking, that maybe there is something like this (pseudocode):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(it was not a click && it was not a form post)
       return "u sure?";
}
```

So, reassuming: Is it possible to get the event that caused .onbeforeunload to fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to unbind the `onbeforeunload` event on a form submission or link click.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('form'), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('submit', function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {}
    });
});
```